# ASTM checksum calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to understand how device is calculating checksum for below ASTM string

```
<STX2P|1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||<CR><ETX>3B<CR><LF>
```

This string shows that the checksum is "3B", while I am trying to find checksum through below code

```
    public static string ConvertStringToHex(string asciiString)
    {
        string hex = "";
        foreach (char c in asciiString)
        {
            int tmp = c;
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
        }
        return hex;
    }
```

But I am getting "3C" as output. Please help me out how could I find checksum.

Comment: ASTM string is wrong, there is no closing > after STX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to compute the Checksum in ASTM...**

> The checksum is computed by adding the binary values of the characters,
>   keeping the least significant eight bits of the result.
>   Each character in the message text is added to the checksum (modulo 256).
>   The checksum is an integer represented by eight bits, it can be considered as two groups of four bits.
>   The groups of four bits are converted to the ASCII characters of the hexadecimal representation.
>   The two ASCII characters are transmitted as the checksum, with the most significant character first.

*I put the line in the file 3B and ran the script which I'll post below this section. I had to add the > sign to fix the STX String.*

> leopard:astm rene$ ./astm.sh ./3B Starting ./astm.sh ...
>
> 2P|1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||3B
>
> 1000100111011 L8B=        111011 
>   LSB used to calculate the MOD 256 L8B
>
> ### MOD= 00111011
>
> and the checksum is.......
>
> MOD= 00111011 M4B= 0011
>
> --->L4B= 1011
>
> Checksum=3B

```
#! /bin/ksh
#set -x

#
############################# Variables #######################
#
integer i=0
HEX=00
integer LEN=0
integer FROM=0
MESSAGE=$1
#blind=0 Not blind
#blind=1 blind, it does not see any astm character till it can see again (blind=0)
HEXTMP=/tmp/hex.tmp
BINTMP=/tmp/bin.tmp
#
############################# Functions #######################
#

astm_checksum() {
print"
# The checksum is computed by adding the binary values of the characters,
# keeping the least significant eight bits of the result.
# Each character in the message text is added to the checksum (modulo 256).
# The checksum is an integer represented by eight bits, it can be considered as two groups of four bits.
# The groups of four bits are converted to the ASCII characters of the hexadecimal representation.
# The two ASCII characters are transmitted as the checksum, with the most significant character first.
"
#converting text in Variable VAR to binairy ...
}


code2hex() {    #Read and convert text written with codes in ASCII like <STX>
printf "\n\n"
awk '
!/^#/   {
        gsub(/<NUL>/,"\x00",$0 )
        gsub(/<SOH>/,"\x01",$0 )
        gsub(/<STX>/,"\x02",$0 )
        gsub(/<ETX>/,"\x03",$0 )
        gsub(/<EOT>/,"\x04",$0 )
        gsub(/<ENQ>/,"\x05",$0 )
        gsub(/<ACK>/,"\x06",$0 )
        gsub( /<LF>/,"\x0A",$0 )
        gsub( /<FF>/,"\x0C",$0 )
        gsub( /<CR>/,"\x0D",$0 )
        gsub(/<NAK>/,"\x15",$0 )
        gsub(/<SYN>/,"\x16",$0 )
        gsub(/<ETB>/,"\x17",$0 )
        gsub(/<CAN>/,"\x18",$0 )
        gsub(/<ESC>/,"\x1B",$0 )
        printf( $0 "\n" )
}
' ${MESSAGE} | hd | cut -c11-58 | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] | xargs | tee ${HEXTMP} | awk '
#example output, one line due to xargs
#02 31 48 7C 5C 5E 26 7C 7C 7C 50 5E 31 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 50 7C 31 7C 0D 03 31 35 0D 0A
#--- first part to filter out control data from real data ---
BEGIN{ RS=" "; blind = 0 ; printf "ibase=16 ; obase=2 ;scale=0;" }
/0A/            { next }                        # <LF>

/02/            { printf("00+"); blind = 0      # <STX>
                } #Eyes are opened (again), after <STX> we start counting
!/02/ && !/03/  { if ( blind == 0 )             
                        printf( $0"+" )
                } #This also includes the <CR> (0D) BEFORE the ETX or ETB!!!
/03/ || /17/    { if ( blind == 0 ) {           
                        printf( $0"\n" ) 
                        blind = 1   }           #The \n = end line and calculate
                } #Blind.. we see nothing till a <STX> is passing again
'| sed 's/+$/\n/p' | tee -a ${HEXTMP} | bc -q | tee ${BINTMP} | while read BIN
do
        #       The two files tee writes to is for debugging only.
        #       
        #       % in bc is modulo but is not described clearly in the man page
        #       scale is default set to 0 but I set it anyway to be sure.
        #
        #Binairy
        printf "BIN= %08d\n" ${BIN}
        #Calculate from where we need to cut the string of bits to have the LSB 8 bits
        LEN=$(echo ${BIN} | wc -c )                     #Not supported by the QNX Shell
        FROM=$(( LEN - 8 ))                             #Not supported by the QNX Shell
        L8B=$(echo ${BIN} | cut -c ${FROM}- )
        printf "L8B=%${LEN}d\n" ${L8B}

        printf "LSB used to calculate the MOD 256\n"
        MOD=$(  echo "ibase=2 ; obase=2 ; ${L8B} % 100000000" | bc -q ) #LSB SUM
        printf "L8B MOD= %08d\n" ${MOD}

        printf "--------------------------- and the checksum is.......  \n"
        printf "MOD= %08d\n" ${MOD}
        M4B=$( printf "%08d\n" ${MOD} | cut -c -4 )
        L4B=$( printf "%08d\n" ${MOD} | cut -c 5- )
        printf "M4B= $M4B\n--->L4B= $L4B\n"
        CD1=$(printf "ibase=2 ; obase=10000 ; ${M4B}\n" | bc -q )
        CD2=$(printf "ibase=2 ; obase=10000 ; ${L4B}\n" | bc -q )
        printf "Checksum=${CD1}${CD2}\n\n"
done
}

############################# main part ################################
test -r "${MESSAGE}" && (echo "Starting $0 ...";cat ${MESSAGE};code2hex) || echo "ERROR: Cannot read file ${MESSAGE}."
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this link: https://www.hendricksongroup.com/code_003.aspx
It explains well. Make sure, you use the load-data after STX and including ETX.
E.g. in the line belof:

```
<STX><Frame Data><CR><ETX><CHECKSUM 1><CHECKSUM 2><CR><LF>
```

use this part of the data used to calculate the MOD 256 checksum

```
<Frame Data><CR><ETX>
```

(sum all load chars and modulo by 256)

**EDIT**

There are few websites, where you can calculate mod 256 (among others) check sums. e.g.: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Let's take the string used in the question as the example:

```
<STX2P|1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||<CR><ETX>3B<CR><LF>
```

As the string is not correct, there is no closing > after STX, w correct it, though it is not relevant for the checksum calculation.

```
<STX>2P|1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||<CR><ETX>3B<CR><LF>
```

Now, the checksum in ASTM 1381 uses the data after  and till the checksum including , this part:

```
P|1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||<CR><ETX>
```

Let's go to the site and paste the string in the "ASCII Input" text field. As the  are replacement for binary data, which can't be displayed as ASCII text, **REMOVE** `<CR><ETX>` and press the button **AnalyseDataAscii**. You will see below calculated chechsum which is wrong as the data is missing `<CR><ETX>`. Ignore the checksum for the first.

[image]

The Hex-Input text field is also updated and displays binary data in the HEX-notation. So add the data for `<CR><ETX>` at the end of the hex-string in the HEX Input. In Hex CR is 0D and ETX is 03, so add 0D03 and press now the other button **AnalyseDataHex**:

[image]

Now you see the correct checksum, which is indeed 3B, exactly as in the message example.
Obviously the code provided by the question author used not correct part of the string and did't replace the placeholders ,  by their hexadecimal representations.