# Calculate checksum for the ASTM data format

Tags: java

I trying to calculate the ASTM data checksum for device communication.

Suppose my data is given bellow :

```
"1R|14|!!!NE|57.50 !   |%||0 to 100|||||ADMIN||20170407120748|01"
```

and expected checksum is [ F4 ] but it gives me [ 04 ] as the checksum.

Here is my code:

```
public static String claculate_checksum(String message){

    String output="";
    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
    int checksum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++){
        checksum +=bytes[i];
    }
    System.out.println("checksum :"+checksum);
    output = String.format("%x", (checksum & 0xFF)).toUpperCase();

    if(output != null)
        return output;
    return output;
}
```

I tried very hard but it seems not working, please help me...

Comment: Are the brackets part of the string?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output.

Comment: Bracket is not a data part.

Comment: Please help me..bro

Comment: Who, me? You ignored my comment. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just this is string  "1R|14|!!!NE|57.50 !   |%||0 to 100|||||ADMIN||20170407120748|01" and accurate checksum is "F4" for this string.

Comment: Like I said, I can't reproduce your result. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Two pointers: 1. `String.getBytes()` uses the default encoding. 2. Bytes are signed in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Same question has been asked by someone else on [stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838240/astm-checksum-calculation). Kindly find solution from there and if you will have still any issue revert back.

also try with below code:

```
public static String getCheckSum(String msg) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        sum += msg.charAt(i);
    }
    sum += 16; //adding CR and ETX AND ETB
    sum = sum % 256;
    String checksum = Integer.toHexString(sum).toUpperCase();
    if (checksum.length() == 1) {
        checksum = "0" + checksum;
    }
    //System.out.println("\n Check Sum is ="+checksum);
    return checksum;
}
```